# c# selenium Alert 'OK' pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, system

i am new to selenium. I'm doing a test automation. The alert window opens. but I want the program to start over when the 'OK' button is pressed. (I need to stay on the same website.)

Thread.Sleep(6000); I do not want to use. I want it to continue by clicking the user 'OK' or ' Cancel' button

thank you for your help

the code is here

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript("alert('hello world');");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Accept();
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but I want the program to start over when the 'OK' button is pressed"? Which program? Your test automation or the application under test?

Comment: You can set the driver's behavior when an unexpected alert is detected...  UnexpectedeAlertBehavior: 
 https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.html  The driver will throw that on the next action... so an alert appears, the driver tries to do something that the alert is preventing... it will then perform the "UnexpectedAlertBehavior" set via setUnhandledPromptBehaviour.  By default I believe it "notifies", which means it throws an exception, but this probably varies by driver.

Comment: Hi Greg, sorry i wrote it wrong.

I want the test to restart

Comment: Ok. So if the alert is displayed, restart the test. If the alert does *not* show up, then continue with the rest of the test. Is that correct?

Comment: actually like that,  When the alert screen comes up, I want the user to wait until they press the ok button and continue the test after pressing it.